# How can I get and store a user's message with python-telegram-bot?

Tags: python-3.x, telegram, python-telegram-bot

I'm writing a Telegram bot that must send an image to a user, get a reply and store it as a string.

I managed to write the script to start the bot and send the image (very basic, I know), but I can't figure out how to get the answer. Here is a MWE of my script:

```
import telegram.ext
token = '1234567890:ABCdEffGH-IJKlm1n23oPqrst_UVzAbcdE4'
bot=telegram.Bot(token=token)

user_id = 567890123
image_path='./image.png'

with open(image_path,'rb') as my_image:
    bot.send_photo(chat_id=user_id,photo=my_image,caption='What is this?')

% Somehow store the answer
% Do some other stuff
```

How can I get and store user's answer?

I can change the script as needed, but to interact with Telegram's API I must use `python-telegram-bot` only.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a flag called waiting_for_response and after sending the image make it *True*.
after that you should add a handler to the bot to recieve users reply. You can do it this way:

```
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler
updater = Updater(token=TOKEN, use_context=True)
dispatcher = updater.dispatcher
handler = RegexHandler(r'.+', function_name)
dispatcher.add_handler(handler)
```

Note: You should replace TOKEN with your own token.
by adding this lines, when user sends a message it calls the *function_name* function and you can define it like this:

```
def function_name(update, context):
    global waiting_for_response
    if waiting_for_response:
        pass
```

You can add whatever you want to do with that message inside of this function using update and context.

Comment: Probably my fault, but I don't understand your answer - how is it supposed to store the message from the user? May you provide a MWE?